# Matlab GPU/CUDA operations using a shared matrix data

Tags: matlab, matrix, cuda, gpu

Is there any way to do an `arrayfun` with a shared matrix in a `gpuArray` type?

In my case I wanted to make the sum of two or more columns of a `gpuArray` matrix, but i dont know how to implement in a `gpuFunction`, `arrayfun` is the best option?

I wanted to make this easy operation in a CUDA because I need to make a million of this kind of operations with the different combinations.

Thank you very much.

Im going to explain the problem better.If you see my problem is like that

> functionarrayfun = @(row)functionMex(data1,data2,row );
>
> i = 1:length(tablaCombinaciones(:,1));%from 1 to end of rows
>
> ratio = arrayfun(functionarrayfun,i);
>
> Error using gpuArray/arrayfun Indexing is not supported. error at line: 6

Comment: As an alternative to `arrayfun`, `gpuArray` and `gpuFunction`, you could try to write your function directly in `CUDA`, compiling it with `nvcc` and then linking it under `Matlab` as a `mex`-file.

Comment: yes i knew it, but im asking because i wanted to know if there were any other way to do it, i wanted to avoid c , but i think i will have to do it

Answer (score 1):

[Arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/arrayfun.html) and [bsxfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/bsxfun.html) work with a gpuArray:

See the example:

```
A = gpuArray.rand(100,2);
B = A(:,1);
C = A(:,2);
bsxfun(@plus,A(:,1),A(:,2))
arrayfun(@(x,y)x+y,A(:,1),A(:,2))
```

Comment: the problem is that in gpu arrayfun you cant use a @ function, it needs to have a written function.In my case i want to have the arrayfun for a function like that
[ ratio(i) ] = functionMex(array1,array2,i )

I think right now its not possible only in matlab you need to use mex, with cuda kernels. or use arrayfire jacket for matlab that is not avaible to buy.
thanks